# Implementing WS-security in Mule webservice causing exception

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, mule-studio, ws-security

I want to implement a ws-security in my CXF webservice ..
I have the following mule flow :-

```
<mule-ss:security-manager>
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>
    <spring:beans>
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <ss:authentication-provider>
                <ss:user-service id="userService">
                    <ss:user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                </ss:user-service>
            </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>

<cxf:ws-security name="inboundSecurityConfig">
<cxf:mule-security-manager />
<cxf:ws-config>
<cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
</cxf:ws-config>
</cxf:ws-security>

<flow name="securedBrewSoapService">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8090" path="designation" doc:name="HTTP">
<cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.getdesignation.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.GetDesignation">
<cxf:ws-security ref="inboundSecurityConfig"/>
</cxf:jaxws-service>
</http:inbound-endpoint>
<component class="com.getdesignation.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.GetDesignationImpl" />
</flow>
```

and now I am using following SOAP request :-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services.test.getDesignation.com/schema/MainData/V1">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">password</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
       </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:getDesignationRequest>
         <v1:DesignationCode>se</v1:DesignationCode>
      </v1:getDesignationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I am getting following exception :-

```
WARN  2014-09-16 20:59:55,198 [[SOAPSecurity].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://services.vertu.getDesignation.com/schema/MainData/V1}GetDesignationService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader.
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:122)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.sendToDestination(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:338)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:144)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.process(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeEvent(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:511)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractTransportMessageProcessTemplate.routeEvent(AbstractTransportMessageProcessTemplate.java:80)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:76)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:63)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:109)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1.run(FlowProcessingPhase.java:62)
    at org.mule.transport.TrackingWorkManager$TrackeableWork.run(TrackingWorkManager.java:267)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "wsse"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3,19]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.InputElementStack.resolveAndValidateElement(InputElementStack.java:492)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2954)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2814)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1062)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.DepthXMLStreamReader.next(DepthXMLStreamReader.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.PartialXMLStreamReader.next(PartialXMLStreamReader.java:46)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1157)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1051)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:158)
    ... 54 more
```

And My SOAP response is :-

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Error reading XMLStreamReader.</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the root cause:

> Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "wsse"

Indeed, the SOAP message you're sending is invalid, as it does not declare the `wsse` namespace.

Here is the corrected SOAP message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
         xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:v1="http://services.test.getDesignation.com/schema/MainData/V1">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security
          xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
       </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:getDesignationRequest>
         <v1:DesignationCode>se</v1:DesignationCode>
      </v1:getDesignationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, as per David's suggestion, I ended up with adding the following:

```
 xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
```

Which is adding namespace for `wsse:` in the Soap request and thus working successfully for me :)